# What is the right way to get lowest prices in another table with laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have these tables to query lowest prices for events tickets;
events, products, product_inventories. I want to list all events with their lowest prices. How can i do it with laravel(every tickets are inside the products table and there are a few price for each ticket in product_inventories).

I tried a few things but i think they are not the best solutions. Here they are:
I defined this function in event model.

```
public function getLowestPriceAttribute()
{
    return ProductInventory::whereIn('product_id',
        Product::where('event_id', $this->id)
            ->pluck('id'))
        ->min('price');
}
```

I can get the lowest price with this query, but there are too many queries like in this photo.

[image: laravel debugbar]

Another thing I've tried that I have not called the attribute but I've changed the query in controller. It runs just one query with this code but i don't think it's right in laravel.

```
$events = Event::leftJoin('products', 'event_id', 'events.id')
    ->leftJoin('product_inventories', 'product_inventories.product_id', 'products.id')
    ->groupBy('events.id')
    ->get(['events.*', \DB::raw('min(product_inventories.price) as min_price')]);
```

Can you help me that how i can optimize this code?

--A question not that much significant: I got 2 queries for each attribute run. How can I reduce it to one?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a relationship method setup within ProductInventory?

```
public function product()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}
```

If you do have it, you can do it like this

```
return ProductInventory::query()
   ->with('product', function ($q) {
     return $q->where('event_id', $this->id);
   })
   ->min('price');
```

Hope this suit your need.

Comment: I changed the func like this but it runs "select min(`price`) as aggregate from `product_inventories`". It doesn't add the event_id condition. I tried a few things but didn't work. Is there a problem with sytnx or something like that?

Comment: It worked when I change the query like this
        return ProductInventory::query()
            ->whereHas('product', function ($q) {
                $q->where('event_id', $this->id);
            })
            ->min('price');

Comment: I apologize, did not test it with ->min, normally just using it with ->get ... good to know you found solution using ->whereHas